# YPDrawSignatureView, Capturing/Saving a Signature in an iOS App

Tags: ios, image, swift, github, uigraphicscontext

I'm using the YPDrawSignatureView custom class on Github (https://github.com/yuppielabel/YPDrawSignatureView), and I set my application up to present modally a new view with the ability to sign your name and save/cancel the image.

I'm using the default save function in the class, but I have absolutely no idea how it works or where it saves to.

Here's the code for that function:

```
       // MARK: Save the Signature as an UIImage
func getSignature() ->UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height))
    self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var signature: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return signature
}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
        @IBAction func saveButton(sender: UIButton) {
    SignatureImage = signatureCaptureField!.getSignature()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I wish to save that signature as an image, and make it appear on the main View of the application (as a signature for a form). Where is it saved to and from where and how am I able to access it in that view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSignature()` should have a return of `UIImage`. This is the stored image of the signature.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let image = signatureCaptureField!.getSignature()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can access the NSData of the image and save it:

```
var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("filename.png")
imageData.writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)
```

Or create a UIImageView to display it back to the user:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.sizeToFit()
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: So if I were to use the second option, making a UImageView, I would have to make it appear on the main view. Can this be accomplished by creating it within the modally presented signature capture view, and then setting its visibility hidden after it gets dismissed, or would I have to create it within the other view that I want to display it in?

Comment: Don't let the code drive you. Drive the code to do what you want.  Whatever view you want to display it in just call `addSubview`. You can put it in any view. Just pass the `image` to the class that will handle the viewing.

Comment: The result is now optional, it only returns a signature if there actually is one. There are also delegate methods/protocol functions passing the state of the view, as well as a bool property for checking if the view contains a signature.